# Apache Camel how to use mail componet (how to write xml)

Tags: xml, apache-camel, blueprint-osgi

I'm trying to get mail with apache Camel with xml.
Please teach me how to write xml.

※ I'd like to check just new mail with xml.And after mail move new to cur.

1. I sent to mail with telnet
2. I checked to that mail in mailbox(new directory(Maildir))
3. I wrote xml.(you can view it below)
4. I deployed jar file and error occured.(you can view it below)

・XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint
  xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0
    https://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd">
  <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
  <route trace="true">
          <to uri="pop3://ipaddress?to=user@domain&amp;username=user@domain&amp;password=user&amp;unseen=true" />
  </route>
  </camelContext>
</blueprint>
```

・Error

```
2018-08-27 04:57:57,360 | INFO  | mix-7.0.0/deploy | fileinstall                      | 4 - org.apache.felix.fileinstall - 3.5.6 | Installing bundle mail-blueprint / 0.1.0.SNAPSHOT
2018-08-27 04:57:57,478 | WARN  | mix-7.0.0/deploy | NamespaceHandlerRegistryImpl     | 28 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.7.1 | NamespaceHandler org.apache.camel.blueprint.handler.CamelNamespaceHandler is behaving badly and should be fixed
2018-08-27 04:57:57,661 | WARN  | mix-7.0.0/deploy | DefaultTypeConverter             | 43 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.16.4 | Overriding type converter from: StaticMethodTypeConverter: public static org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQDestination org.apache.activemq.camel.converter.ActiveMQConverter.toDestination(java.lang.String) to: StaticMethodTypeConverter: public static org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQDestination org.apache.activemq.camel.converter.ActiveMQConverter.toDestination(java.lang.String)
2018-08-27 04:57:57,661 | WARN  | mix-7.0.0/deploy | DefaultTypeConverter             | 43 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.16.4 | Overriding type converter from: InstanceMethodTypeConverter: public org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQMessage org.apache.activemq.camel.converter.ActiveMQMessageConverter.toMessage(org.apache.camel.Exchange) throws javax.jms.JMSException to: InstanceMethodTypeConverter: public org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQMessage org.apache.activemq.camel.converter.ActiveMQMessageConverter.toMessage(org.apache.camel.Exchange) throws javax.jms.JMSException
2018-08-27 04:57:57,661 | WARN  | mix-7.0.0/deploy | DefaultTypeConverter             | 43 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.16.4 | Overriding type converter from: InstanceMethodTypeConverter: public org.apache.camel.Processor org.apache.activemq.camel.converter.ActiveMQMessageConverter.toProcessor(javax.jms.MessageListener) to: InstanceMethodTypeConverter: public org.apache.camel.Processor org.apache.activemq.camel.converter.ActiveMQMessageConverter.toProcessor(javax.jms.MessageListener)
2018-08-27 04:57:57,667 | WARN  | mix-7.0.0/deploy | BeanRecipe                       | 28 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.7.1 | Object to be destroyed is not an instance of UnwrapperedBeanHolder, type: null
2018-08-27 04:57:57,667 | ERROR | mix-7.0.0/deploy | BlueprintContainerImpl           | 28 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.7.1 | Unable to start blueprint container for bundle mail-blueprint/0.1.0.SNAPSHOT
org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: Unable to initialize bean .camelBlueprint.factory.camel-2
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.runBeanProcInit(BeanRecipe.java:738)[28:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.7.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate2(BeanRecipe.java:848)[28:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.7.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:811)[28:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.7.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe$1.call(AbstractRecipe.java:79)[28:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.7.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)[:1.8.0_181]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:88)[28:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.7.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstances(BlueprintRepository.java:255)[28:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.7.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstance(BlueprintRepository.java:233)[28:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.7.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.create(BlueprintRepository.java:148)[28:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.7.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.getComponentInstance(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:796)[28:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.7.1]
        at org.apache.camel.blueprint.handler.CamelNamespaceHandler$CamelDependenciesFinder.process(CamelNamespaceHandler.java:980)[40:org.apache.camel.camel-blueprint:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.processProcessors(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:569)[28:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.7.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.doRun(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:395)[28:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.7.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:276)[28:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.7.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:300)[28:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.7.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:269)[28:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.7.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:265)[28:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.7.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.modifiedBundle(BlueprintExtender.java:255)[28:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.7.1]
        at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:500)[39:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.1]
        at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:433)[39:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.1]
        at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$AbstractTracked.track(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:725)[39:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.1]
        at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:463)[39:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.1]
        at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$BundleEventHook.event(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:422)[39:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.1]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.invokeBundleEventHook(SecureAction.java:1179)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.6.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.createWhitelistFromHooks(EventDispatcher.java:730)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.6.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.fireBundleEvent(EventDispatcher.java:485)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.6.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireBundleEvent(Felix.java:4541)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.6.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2172)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.6.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:998)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.6.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundle(DirectoryWatcher.java:1253)[4:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.6]
        at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1225)[4:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.6]
        at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.doProcess(DirectoryWatcher.java:512)[4:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.6]
        at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(DirectoryWatcher.java:361)[4:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.6]
        at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:312)[4:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.6]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Route has no outputs: Route[[From[pop3://ipaddress?to=user@domain&username=user@domain&password=user&unseen=true]] -> []]
        at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinitionHelper.sanityCheckRoute(RouteDefinitionHelper.java:353)
        at org.apache.camel.core.xml.AbstractCamelContextFactoryBean.prepareRoutes(AbstractCamelContextFactoryBean.java:400)
        at org.apache.camel.core.xml.AbstractCamelContextFactoryBean.setupRoutes(AbstractCamelContextFactoryBean.java:377)
        at org.apache.camel.blueprint.CamelContextFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:322)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)[:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.8.0_181]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)[:1.8.0_181]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:299)[28:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.7.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.invoke(BeanRecipe.java:980)[28:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.7.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.runBeanProcInit(BeanRecipe.java:736)[28:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.7.1]
        ... 33 more
2018-08-27 04:57:57,678 | INFO  | mix-7.0.0/deploy | fileinstall                      | 4 - org.apache.felix.fileinstall - 3.5.6 | Started bundle: file:/opt/apache-servicemix-7.0.0/deploy/mail-blueprint-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Thanks
===============================================-

I fixed code. And I recieve servicemix.log 1-minute intervals below.
And I checked mail(new directory) move to cur directory.
But I couldn't check content of telnet DATA on servicemix.log
I expect below behavior

【question】
Why there was no error when I add below code?

```
<log message="received the message with xml" />
```

・Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<blueprint
  xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0
    https://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd">

  <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">

  <route id="email-consumer-entrypoint-route" trace="true">
          <from uri="pop3://ipadress?to=user@domain&amp;username=user@domain&amp;password=user&amp;unseen=true&amp;consumer.delay=60000&amp;mapMailMessage=false&amp;fetchSize=1" />
          <log message="received the message with xml" />
  </route>
  </camelContext>

</blueprint>
```

・servicemix.log

```
2018-08-27 07:19:42,960 | INFO  |  pop3://ipaddress | email-consumer-entrypoint-route  | 43 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.16.4 | received the message with xml
2018-08-27 07:20:44,444 | INFO  |  pop3://ipaddress | email-consumer-entrypoint-route  | 43 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.16.4 | received the message with xml
```

・expect behavior

1. there is no error when I deploy jar file and move
   /opt/serviecmix/deploy directory.
2. check the servicemix.log and find only new content of new directory
   file(mail)
3. check the cur directory and find mail that move from new directory.

Thanks

===============================================-

I fixed  and checked get mail on servicemix.log
And I have new question.

【question】
・I'd like to use "to"tag below code.
  But it couldn't read "new directory(file)" and couldn't write log message on servicemix.log.
  Can I wrote endpoint to "to"tag like below?

```
<route id="email-consumer-entrypoint-route" trace="true">
 <from uri="direct:start" />
 <log message="received the message with xml" />
 <to uri="imap://ipaddress?to=user@domain&amp;username=user@domain&amp;password=user&amp;unseen=true&amp;consumer.delay=60000&amp;mapMailMessage=false&amp;fetchSize=1" />
</route>
```

・fixed code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint
  xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0
    https://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd">

  <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">

  <route id="email-consumer-entrypoint-route" trace="true">
    <from uri="imap://ipaddress?to=user@domain&amp;username=user@domain&amp;password=user&amp;unseen=true&amp;consumer.delay=60000&amp;mapMailMessage=false&amp;fetchSize=1" />
    <log message="received the message with xml" />
  </route>

  </camelContext>

</blueprint>
```

Thanks
===============================================-

Thank you so much trilok.
I have new question.

【question】

1. I would like to work mailapi just one time to use sheduler(like
   quartz2 component).（want to specify a time） I am trying to use
   quartz2 componet, but didn't move because of invalid code. you can
   see that code below. How should I write?
2. I don't use "consumer.delay"parameter, how can I stop that function?

・ERROR

```
 - 2.16.4 | Error occurred during starting Camel: CamelContext(camel-2) due CronExpression '0 0/5 * * * ?@domain' is invalid.
java.lang.RuntimeException: CronExpression '0 0/5 * * * ?@domain' is invalid.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'apache Camel with xml' , I presume that you mean to say is Spring DSL.

Another thing is, To receive an email using camel, you would have use camel mail component. It will be something like to receive an email-

```
<route id="email-consumer-entrypoint-route">
            <from uri="imaps://imap.gmail.com?username=username@gmail.com&password=p@ssword&delete=false&unseen=true&consumer.delay=60000&mapMailMessage=false&fetchSize=1" />
```

For more details please take a look at http://camel.apache.org/mail.html

Comment: thank you for your kind answer.
I fixed my code and edited question.

Comment: You have used <from/> which is to receive emails. Please check If you are receiving emails. If not, try to use imap and check.

To send the received emails to a target, use <to uri="target_endpoint" />

Comment: Thank you so much.And I refixed my code and add new question.
Please check it 
Thanks

Comment: <to/> is used to post to an endpoint and <from/> is used to receive. In another words, <from/> is consumer and <to/> is producer.
imap is used to receive emails,  smtp can be used to send emails.

Comment: Thank you so much.I can understand.
And I have a another question.please check it.
Thanks